# can't get data angular service to component

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular-services

my service function  is ..

```
 getPro():any{
    this.database.all("SELECT * FROM product").then(rows => {
        console.log("hello pro hear....")
        let proList:Product[]=[]

        for(var row in rows) {

            proList.push(new Product(rows[row][0],rows[row][1],rows[row][2],rows[row][3],rows[row][4]))
           /* proList.push({
                "id": rows[row][0],
                "name": rows[row][1],
                "hsn": rows[row][2],
                "rate": rows[row][3],
                "tax":rows[row][4]
            })*/
            console.log("list ",rows[row][0])
        }
        console.log("total pro ",proList.length)
        return "hello"
    }, error => {
        console.log("SELECT ERROR", error);
    });
}
```

and my component is ..

```
 proList:any

fatchPro(){
   this.proList= this.dataservice.getPro();
    console.log("fatchPro" ,this.proList)
}
```

but when i console.log(proList) it will get undefined

how can i solve this error...

Comment: your getPro method does not return anything

Comment: it's   return "hello" see sir..

Comment: No, the return hello is inside the promise's callback

Comment: the `this.database.all()` returns `"hello"` but the `getPro()` method doesnt, i think you need to do `return this.database.all().....`

Comment: thank you sir its work  thaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaank you

Answer (score 1):

Try that

```
 getPro():any{
    return this.database.all("SELECT * FROM product").then(rows => {
        console.log("hello pro hear....")
        let proList:Product[]=[]

        for(var row in rows) {

            proList.push(new Product(rows[row][0],rows[row][1],rows[row][2],rows[row][3],rows[row][4]))
           /* proList.push({
                "id": rows[row][0],
                "name": rows[row][1],
                "hsn": rows[row][2],
                "rate": rows[row][3],
                "tax":rows[row][4]
            })*/
            console.log("list ",rows[row][0])
        }
        console.log("total pro ",proList.length)
        return "hello"
    }, error => {
        console.log("SELECT ERROR", error);
    });
}

fatchPro(){
   this.proList= this.dataservice.getPro().then(list =>
   {
   this.proList = list;
    console.log("fatchPro" ,this.proList)
   });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `dataservice.getPro function` is creating a Promise and subscribing to it, but not returning anything itself. Therefore the `proList` is not set. You can return the Promise and subscribe to it in your `fatchPro function`:

```
getPro(): Promise<any>{
    return this.database.all("SELECT * FROM product").then(rows => {
        return rows.map(row => new Product(row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4]));
    }, error => {
         console.log("SELECT ERROR", error);
    });
}
```

-

```
proList: Product[];

fatchPro() {
   this.dataservice.getPro().then(proList => {
       this.proList = proList;
       console.log("fatchPro" ,this.proList);
    });
}
```